# how to make a game like this with cocos2d?

Tags: scroll, cocos2d-iphone

This game:
http://armorgames.com/play/4421/toss-the-turtle

if I will make a game like this , fist I think I should use the box2d to create a gravity world. Then I need to follow the hero sprite or it will fly out the screen.

The problem is how to follow the hero sprite?
The first I think of how to solve the "follow" problem is to move the background, but it is a gravity environment, I don't know how to do it, I only know how to do it when the sprite move straitly.

So how to do, is there any example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the background by just setting the CCLayer's position. This won't affect the physics world. And yes, you probably will want box2d. Check out this tutorial to see how to get started with box2d: http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls.